# Book suggestions for Low-level ethernet/networking (e.g. MII)

Tags: networking, frame, ethernet, xilinx, raw-ethernet

I had a colleague who is using Xilinx's LocalLink [TEMAC](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/xps_ll_temac.pdf)

While I find the DS interesting, I would like to learn more about the basics of it. Does anyone have any recommendations for a good low-level intro to networking/ethernet book?

I don't need to know "how to be a good network administrator", but rather interfaces like the MII, GMII, and how they communicate with different PHYs that are on the market. My questions that I'd like to learn about are similar to:

What is ethernet? 
How are packets structured? 
What is a preamble and how is it used?
What is a frame?

I'd also be interested in online sites if it's really much easier to learn from in your opinion. If there is a book series, I would be open to that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best networking books I've found is "The TCP/IP Guide: A Comprehensive, Illustrated Internet Protocols Reference" [http://www.amazon.com/TCP-Guide-Comprehensive-Illustrated-Protocols/dp/159327047X/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1312296674&sr=8-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159327047X). The only thing this doesn't cover in great detail is the actual layer 1 stuff. Well even then it goes over some basic details, but the book is excellent for most anything you need to know regarding networks, packets, headers, etc....

Comment: Looks like a good place to start; thanks!